# A Cipher with 2 methods for encryption/decryption

Tags: scala, caesar-cipher

I'd like advice on how this could be written more efficiently, idiomatically, or just anything that could be improved upon.

I'd also like to know if there's an alternative to my `forString` method; I couldn't find anything similar in the library (and Scalex seems to be down, so I couldn't search).

There are 2 provided ways of encrypting a message:

```
val message:String = "Hello World!"
val key:String = "Key"

val encrypted = Cipher(message).simpleOffset(5)
println(encrypted) "Mjqqt%\twqi&"
val decrypted = Cipher(encrypted).simpleOffset(-5)
println(decrypted) "Hello World!"

val encrypted2 = Cipher(message).encryptWith(key)
println(encrypted2) "5l?Yv;Dv?Yk<"
val decrypted2 = Cipher(encrypted2).decryptWith(key)
println(decrypted2) "Hello World!"
```

and the code:

```
class Cipher(message:String) {
    val cHARMIN = 32 //Lower bound
    val cHARMAX = 126 //Upper bound

    //"Wraps" a character, so it doesn't go under cHARMIN, or over cHARMAX
    //Takes an Int so the Char can't underflow prior to being passed in
    private def wrap(n:Int):Char =
        if (n > cHARMAX) (n - cHARMAX + cHARMIN).toChar
        else if (n < cHARMIN) (n - cHARMIN + cHARMAX).toChar
        else n.toChar

    private def forString(str:String)(f:Char => Char):String = {
        var newStr = ""
        for(c <- str) { newStr += f(c) }
        newStr
    }

    //Creates a repeated key that's at least as long as the message to be encrypted
    private def getRepKey(key:String):String =
        if (key.length >= message.length) key
            else key * (message.length / key.length + 1)

    //Modifies a letter in the message, based on the respective letter in the key,
    //    and the given binary operator
    private def modifyWithStringWith(f:(Int,Int) => Int)(strKey:String):String = {
        var newString = ""
        (message zip getRepKey(strKey)).foreach { case (c1,c2) =>
                newString += wrap( f(c1,c2) ) }
        newString
    }

    //Offsets each character in a String by a given offset
    def simpleOffset(offset:Int):String =
        forString(message) { (c:Char) =>
            wrap((c + offset).toChar)
    }

    //Encrypts/Decrypts using another String as the key
    def encryptWith(key:String):String =
        modifyWithStringWith(_+_)(key)

    def decryptWith(key:String):String =
        modifyWithStringWith(_-_)(key)
}

object Cipher {
    def apply(msg:String):Cipher = new Cipher(msg)
}
```

Comment: Um, Scala Strings have **map**.  No need at all for your forString method.  http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/strings.html

Comment: @itsbruce That doesn't return a String though.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Read the documentation.  http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps

Comment: @itsbruce Weird. I was getting back an IndexedSeq (or something like that), and it wasn't readily convertible to a String. Thanks

Comment: There also seem to be some unseen (untested?) errors in your code.  Your **wrap** function fails if a character has a numeric value higher than 220 or lower than -63.  I don't think its logic is right even within those bounds.  Are you aware that the third line of your simpleOffset method is useless?

Comment: @itsbruce No, I should have tested it more. And they line is a leftover from debugging that I missed.

Comment: And I think I can change `wrap` to use `mod`, which shouldn't break.

Comment: I imagine you experimented with map in the repl, where an IndexedSeq would have been returned because there was no context, so the repl chose the most generic type it could.  When the for...yield loop is the last line, returning the function value, Scala can tell precisely which type to use from the function signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**forString**

As discussed already in comments, your `forString` method is not needed because `map` *is* available to Scala Strings.  But if you do need to construct such a method, your design is not best practice.  Specifically, you create a local `var`, append to it repeatedly from within a for block and return that.

This block

```
    var newStr = ""
    for(c <- str) { newStr += f(c) }
    newStr
```

can be written simply as

```
    for (c <- str) yield f(c)
```

Updating an external var from within a for block is a stateful, potentially error-prone, very non-FP practice which you should use with care.  It is not needed here.  Leave the compiler to construct and return the string - it *will* be more efficient and your code is cleaner as a result.

(It will be more efficient because in the **for-yield** block, the compiler *knows* it is creating a sequence one item at a time and begins each step with a ready pointer to the end of the collection.  In contrast, when your code explicitly appends to the end of a sequence each time, it has to traverse the entire sequence each time.  No handy reference to the end of the string is cached. Appending to strings is expensive.)

**wrap**

Both the original version and the modulo alternative in your answer use `if... else if...` then chains.  These are a [bad smell](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223718/specifics-of-switch-and-if-statements/223731#223731).  All three of your options depend upon the value of the input parameter, but nothing about an if-elseif-then chain forces you to cite that parameter in each successive condition.  Pattern matching would at least ensure that the same object is being assessed for each action.  That would look something like this:

```
n match {
    case _ if (n > cHARMAX) => (cHARMIN + (n - cHARMAX) % cRANGE)
    case _ if (n < cHARMIN) => (cHARMAX - (cHARMIN - n) % cRANGE)
    case _ => n
}
```

However, although I am still not sure why you have this function in there, I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
n match {
    case _ if (n > cHARMAX) => cHARMIN + ((n - cHARMIN) % cRANGE)
    case _ if (n < cHARMIN) => cHARMAX - ((cHARMIN - n) % cRANGE)
    case _ => n
}
```

**Key length**

Repeating the key until it is as long as the message is a waste of resources (more so, the longer the message becomes).  Just leave the key in its original size.  There are several ways to iterate through the message and (effectively or literally) use modulo arithmetic to fetch the corresponding character from the key.

1. Create an [endlessly repeating Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097851/scala-repeat-a-finite-list-infinitely) from the key (fast and efficient).  Then you can just iterate through both in step (for example, using `zipped`)
2. `for (i <- message.indices) yield myFunction(message(i), key(i % key.length))` (reasonably fast and efficient)
3. Use [`zipWithIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213323/how-can-i-use-map-and-receive-an-index-as-well-in-scala) and `map` to turn the message into a list of tuples (each character bundled with its index) and then iterate through that, using modulo arithmetic on the index to fetch the right key character (less efficient, slower).

Option 1 is best

**Cipher class design**

The most curious thing about your `Cipher` class is that its Apply method takes a *message* as a parameter.  This is not good OO design and it also inverts the meaning of the word (OK, cipher *can* mean an encrypted text but more commonly it means one particular encryption method with one particular key choice).  It would make more sense for a cipher object to have the key (and possibly some other parameters like, for example, the range of valid characters) as a field.  So you could create a cipher instance containing the key "MyAmazingSecretCode" and then use that object to encrypt or decrypt as many messages as you want.  As things stand, `Cipher` is mostly a java-like utility class containing static methods, offering no way to maintain any state.

Having the two different encryption options in one class is also less good.  Are you going to rewrite this class every time you add another variant on the encryption method?

Consider, instead, a basic `Cipher` class or trait or even interface, which describes the key interface methods (setting the secret, encrypting, decrypting).  If it is a class or trait, you could also design an "encryption strategy" trait from which specific encryption methods (your simple offset and your substitution key, as two examples) could be derived.  You could then mix the appropriate strategy trait into the Cipher class to provide a working cipher.  If you choose to make `Cipher` an interface, then your two strategies could be separate classes which each incorporate that interface.  Which to choose depends on larger design considerations.

Answer (score 2):

**Style**

When you declare a type of a function, value, or variable, add a space between the `:` and the type.

```
// this
def func(...): T = {...}
val xs: List[T] = List[T](...)

// not this
def func(...):T = {...}
val xs:List[T] = List[T](...)
```

**Code**

Below is another interpretation of how you might write your code. I've separated all your original parts into a set of case classes and one trait. For example, `simpleOffset` is now called `Caesar` and it extends the `Cipher` trait. I imagine you were aware of it, but `simpleOffset` was essentially a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). Likewise, all the logic you had embedded in the rest of your program, particularly how you were dealing with the the `key` string and the `wrap` function resulted in something close to a [Vigenere cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher). In order to align the `key` with the input text I choose to utilize a method on the list class, `sliding`, which works as follows:

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val ys = xs.sliding(2, 2).toList
// ys == List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
```

Well, that about sums up the changes I would make. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to comment! :)

```
case class PlainText(msgStr: String) 
case class CipherText(msgStr: String) 
case class Key(keyStr: String)

trait Cipher {
    val max = 126
    def E(p: PlainText): CipherText
    def D(c: CipherText): PlainText
}

case class Caesar(shift: Int) extends Cipher {
    def op(xs: List[Char], f: (Char) => Int): String = {
        val xss = xs map(c => f(c))
        (xss map(i => i.toChar)).mkString
    }

    def E(p: PlainText): CipherText = {
        val str = op(p.msgStr.toList, (c: Char) => c + shift % max)
        CipherText(str)
    }

    def D(c: CipherText): PlainText = {
        val str = op(c.msgStr.toList, (c: Char) => c - shift % max)
        PlainText(str)
    }
}

case class Vigenere(k: Key) extends Cipher {
    val blockSize = k.keyStr.length()

    def op(xs: List[Char], f: (Char, Char) => Int): String = {
        val ys = xs.sliding(blockSize, blockSize).toList
        val zs = (ys map(_ zip k.keyStr)).flatten

        (for {
            (m, k) <- zs
            result = f(m, k).toChar
        } yield result).mkString
    }

    def E(p: PlainText): CipherText = {
        val msgStr = op(p.msgStr.toList, (m: Char, k: Char) => m + k % max)
        CipherText(msgStr)
    }

    def D(c: CipherText): PlainText = {
        val msgStr = op(c.msgStr.toList, (m: Char, k: Char) => m - k % max)
        PlainText(msgStr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `%`, `wrap` no longer breaks:

```
val cRANGE = cHARMAX - cHARMIN

private def wrap(n:Int):Char = (
        if (n > cHARMAX)        (cHARMIN + (n - cHARMAX) % cRANGE)
        else if (n < cHARMIN)   (cHARMAX - (cHARMIN - n) % cRANGE)
        else n
    ).toChar
```

Comment: shame about the **if... else if... else...**

Comment: I was trying to emulate guards. How would you arrange it?

Comment: Funny you should mention guards.  Proper pattern matching with real guards would be better than the if else if chain with pseudo-guards.  However, this is actually one simple arithmetical function with only slight variations and would be better written that way.  Will try to find time for an answer tonight.

Comment: Is this function supposed to limit the *encrypted* text to that range of characters, or is valid input only allowed from that range?  Because the function affects both, the way this code is designed.